# Indenting the content of the first column of an HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table of hierarchical data (tree data structure) of varying depth and I want to render it using an HTML table in which just the content of the first column of the table will be indented according to the depth of each row that is known beforehand:

```
"comment one" (row=1, depth=0)
"comment two" (row=2, depth=0)
    "comment three" (row=3, depth=1)
        "comment four" (row=4, depth=2)
"comment five" (row=5, depth=0)
```

Now how can I achieve this?

[image: KDE System Monitor]

And I know I can easily do it by defining CSS classes for each depth, but I am looking for a general solution.

Comment: Can you provide an example that represents the table structure? This would give something to work with and allow to give a fitting answer.

Comment: There is no real way to "indent" rows of a table. You could apply CSS properties to the table rows, that "rob" them of their table-row display type - but then you will be losing table "features" as well (such as that the columns align with each other.) Other than applying a padding-left on the first cells, I don't immediately see a workable solution here. But perhaps the root of the problem is that a table is not the right element to use for data structured this way to begin with.

Comment: I think you might have to use grid or nested unordered lists. There's no realistic way of converting any attribute to a padding or margin. AFAIK the only property that takes an attribute is the ::before and ::after pseudo elements. Any other support is experimental only. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr#browser_compatibility

Comment: What does this data look like that you need to use a table?

Answer (score 1):

##### Alternative solution

Mr. Polywhirl answer may be what you are looking for.
I still want to present an alternative solution. It doesn't fit what you need, but may be suited for other people browsing this question with different case.

For an automatic indentation, you can use CSS [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).
The trick is to rotate the table, in order to simulate indentation.
And then rotate the individual items in the opposite way to have them straight.

I like this solution for being polyvalent, it adapts to any number of item.

```js
i = 3
function addElement(){
  table = document.getElementById("indented-table");
  table.innerHTML += `<tr><td>${++i}</td></tr>`;
}
```

```css
#indented-table{
  transform-origin: top left;
    transform: skewX(20deg);
}

#indented-table tr{
  background-color: #aaf;
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

```html
<table id="indented-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button onclick="addElement()">Add</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can define a style to add padding to the table cells, based on the data attribute.

```css
[data-row-depth="0"] { padding-left: 0; }
[data-row-depth="1"] { padding-left: 0.5rem; }
[data-row-depth="2"] { padding-left: 1.0rem; }
[data-row-depth="3"] { padding-left: 1.5rem; }
[data-row-depth="4"] { padding-left: 2.0rem; }

/* and so on... */
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="0">A</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="1">A-1</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="2">A-1-1</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="3">A-1-1-1</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="1">A-2</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="0">B</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="0">C</td></tr>
    <tr><td data-row-depth="1">C-1</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's OK if you already know the maximum depth.