# How can I use JavaScript to simulate the CSS attr() function?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I use JavaScript to simulate the [attr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/attr) function? For example I want to indent the following paragraph using the value of `data-indent` as we do by `p { text-indent: attr(data-indent em) }`.

```
<p data-indent=4>Hello World :-)</p>
```

**EDIT:** Most of you may not understand what I learned today because my question seems silly to you, but I think @G-Cyrillus's answer deserves more attention. Actually first I should mention that I was stupid not thinking about inline style. I thought it is neater to avoid that when you can use HTML class and id. But today I learned inline style is inevitable in some situations. This question was asked to solve my [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74125173/2817520). Now I can easily use an HTML table to render a tree data structure without JavaScript in a neat manner.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute

Comment: Alternatively https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Comment: or via CSS , have like any library, selectors ready made to use : `[data-indent=4]{text-indent:4em;}` CSS var() could also be used via a style attribute : `<p style='--indent:4em'>Hello World :-)</p> <p style='--indent:2em'>Hello World :-)</p>` and a single selector p{text-indent:var(--indent)}`

Comment: @G-Cyrillus I don't know beforehand what the value of `data-indent` would be. It is generated based on a SQL query.

Comment: okay, **a)** i proposed to make your selectors ahead [data-indent=1] , [data-indent=4] and so on (like bootsrap does for col-X , nobody use them all, but there all there)  **b)** use a var() CSS via a style attribute instead a data-attribute . inserting a number in any of these attribute is not different. :)

Comment: @G-Cyrillus But the query may return many different indentation numbers, say 4, 8, 64, and there is no limit on that.

Comment: okay, then the var() CSS option is the one that cost the less. You only have to  ;)fill the attribute and a single inside the CSS sheet. ex https://jsfiddle.net/d6Lbrq43/

Comment: another example maybe clearer for what it does : https://jsfiddle.net/d6Lbrq43/1/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus Fascinating, I was looking for this whole day :D, please post it as an answer.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus You may not know, but to me your comment is a gem buried here in the comment section.

Comment: Okay, i made an answer from the comment, hope it is clear/clean enough to be usefull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From earlier comment :

> okay, then the `var()` CSS option is the one that cost the less. You only have to ;)fill the attribute (`style` instead `data-X` ) and a single rule inside the CSS sheet. ex: https://jsfiddle.net/d6Lbrq43/1/

You could avoid JavaScript if your attributes are filled on server side, you could use the style attribute to set a CSS variable that will be avalaible for that single element . see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/var to dig into it .

Here is an example (from the fiddle linked earlier) to demonstrate the idea:

```css
* {/* here the demo is for a generic example of the effect on any tag */
  text-indent: var(--indent);
  /* this value can even be used for any other use */
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, gray var(--indent), yellow var(--indent))
}

[style]:after {
  content: attr(style);
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1 style='--indent:4em'>Hello World :-)</h1>
<p style='--indent:2em'>Hello World :-)</p>
<p style='--indent:44em'>Hello World :-)</p>
<div style='--indent:12em'>Hello World :-)</div>
<p style='--indent:34em'>Hello World :-)</p>
<p style='--indent:0em'>Hello World :-)</p>
<p >Hello World :-)</p>
```

CSS `var()` can have any value, and if this value is a number (with or without units) it can also be used for calculation inside a `calc()`, set a `font-size`, parts of a color, whatever you can think of ... as long as it can be inserted in a CSS rule.

Answer (score 2):

Select the elements based on the attribute, loop over them and set an inline style based on the value in the data-attribute.

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-indent]');
for (const element of elements) {
  element.style.textIndent = `${element.dataset.indent}em`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an example piece of code:

```
document.querySelector("p").style.text-indent = document.querySelector("p").getAttribute("data-indent")+"em";
```